# Creating a Table B which has only a subset of Table A attributes

Tags: sql, sqlite, postgresql

Database software: SQLITE

Consider this scenario:
Table X has attributes: A,B,C,D,1,2,3,4
Table Y needs to have: A,B,C,D

The database size is bordering on 30GB. It seems redundant to store the records of A,B,C,D.

I was wondering if there is any way we can create a "virtual" table such that if the program calls for the Table Y it will still read data from X but only the A,B,C,D attributes.

Any help is much appreciated!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
CREATE VIEW B AS (SELECT a,b,c FROM X)
```

For SQLite see [this link](http://sqlite.org/lang_createview.html).
For Postgres see [here](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/sql-createview.html).

Comment: One question: From within a C++ code does the VIEW "B" behave like a table? Does invoking table name B actually the same as invoking VIEW B?

Comment: You're welcome, please click the hook on the left to mark this answer as correct then.